# Как поменять размер выделенного текста в JTextArea?

Tags: java

Пишу в образовательных целях примитивный блокнот. Каким образом менять размер выделенного текста или цвет или делать текст например жирным.
Я знаю как это сделать со всем текстом вместе, но хочется именно менять параметры выделенного текста.

Answer (score 2):

`JTextArea` позволяет изменять только цвет выделенного текста с помощью метода `setSelectionColor`. Для остального вам нужно использовать не `JTextArea`, a `JEditorPane` или `JTextPane`. Эта компонента может иметь несколько стилей для разных частей текста, так как в качестве модели имеет `StyledDocument`. Больше информации и примеры [здесь](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html). Далее вам нужно добавить слушатель событий изменений, связанных с выделением текста - `CaretListener`.
Кстати стандартный блокнот не позволяет использовать разные стили.